# I want to make a pair of 2 ways loudspeakers reusing the drivers from two old identical 5.1 systems. Make it sense?

Tags: audio, speakers, 5.1, diy, reused

I have two identical 5.1 systems that doesn't work (I think the problem in both are the power supply, but I don´t care about that, I'm interesting on reusing the drivers, they are working fine). The pair of 5.1 sets are logitech x-530 models, detailed specs: (https://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/5,941-9.html).

I have the idea of reusing the satellites drivers and the subwoofer of each old system, to build a pair of stereo two ways speakers. I want to build two boxes to accommodate the 10 small drivers for mid/high frequencies and the sub to cover the low frequencies. I would buy a pair of two ways passive filters to separate the frequencies (2 ways passive crossovers). I will power the new resultant speakers with a regular 2.0 channels amplifier (38 RMS watts per channel, 4-8 ohms capable).

I have some questions about this project:

1.- how can I wire the 10 small speakers to connect them to the high-pass filter with a total of 4 or 8 ohms resistance?
2.- What point do you recommend for crossing frequencies?
3.- Any cabinet sizes recommendations (I prefer sealed design)?
4.- Do you miss any aspect in my thoughts about this project?

Many thanks!

Comment: Cabinet sizes are calculated specifically for the drivers and crossover's  you intend to use. The "crossing frequencies" ( *resisters, capacitors, coils etc*. ) are dependent on the drivers specs and the other drivers in the set up and the enclosure. **We can not answer these questions for you here**.  There are several speaker building forums, tutorials and resources on the web.

Comment: I have my own idea about the crossing point, I have my idea about cabinet size and design. I was asking for a second expert opinion. Of course I know thousands of sites with a enormous amounts of information (who do not?). I was seeking for some advice, an opinion, not just information.

Comment: **This is not the place to ask for opinions**, second or otherwise.  If you have a **problem** you need to solve and it can be **answered** here then it is appropriate here. Opinions and discussions should be taken to a forum. Know one can give you the information you want with out knowing 100% of the variables and specs for your project.